# angularjs wrong locale time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I am struggling with a complete mystery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have 2 AngularJS apps using the very same base (Angular 1.5.6)

I created a directive embedding a DatePicker. This directive is used in both apps. It enable user to eiter pick a date, either input it directly.

In one of the apps, if I do console.log(myDate) i get :  Date {Thu Apr 16 1964 02:00:00 GMT+0100}

In the other one I get :  Date {Thu Apr 16 1964 02:00:00 GMT+0200}

Aditionnaly this behaviour is found in Firefox AND Chrome, so I guess my second application is setting the timezone somewhere....

I can't understand at all why the locale time is different. Is it possible it comes from some secret conf on the 2nd app ?

For information I am using angular locale function in both.

```
<script src="vendors/bower_components/angular/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
```

Thank you very much to the one who can successfully resolve that complete mystery !

Regards.

EDIT: Here is the directive I am using:

```
.directive('fmkDateOrUpdate', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            titre : "@",
            enModification : "=",
            modele : "=",
            idValue  : "@?",
            classCss  : "@?",
            fullDate : "@?",
            textByDefault : "@?"
        },
        replace : false,
        transclude : true,
        template :  "<div class='ligneTitreValeur {{classCss}}'>" +
                    "   <div class='titre'>{{titre}} :</div>" +
                    "   <div class='valeur' ng-if='!fullDate' ng-hide='enModification'>{{ modele | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</div>" +
                    "   <div class='valeur' ng-if='fullDate' ng-hide='enModification'>{{ modele  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy à HH:mm'}}</div>" +
                    "   <div class='valeurEnModification' ng-hide='!enModification'>" + 
                    "       <div class='date-picker input-group' ng-class=\"{ 'is-opened': opened == true }\" ng-controller='datePick'>" +
                    "           <div class='fg-line' ng-class=\"{ 'fg-toggled': opened == true }\">" +
                    "               <input placeholder='{{textByDefault}}' ng-click=\"open($event, 'opened')\" type='text' class='form-control check-valid-date' uib-datepicker-popup='{{format}}' show-weeks='false' ng-model='$parent.modele' is-open='opened' datepicker-options='dateOptions'  close-text='Close' id='{{idValue}}'/>" +
                    "           </div>" +
                    "       </div>" +
                    "   </div>" +
                    "</div>",
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            var element = $element[0].querySelector('input');
            element.addEventListener('click', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.focus();
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

And there is the usage of this directive :

```
<fmk-date-or-update titre="Date de naissance"
    modele="personne.dateNaissance"
    en-modification="enModification()" class="">
</fmk-date-or-update>
```

EDIT 2 :
This is coming from the  of my 2nd application. The myDate object is linked by the ng-model object... I still don't get it

[image]

Comment: Could you show how `myDate` is assigned?

Comment: With this directive I can assign the date directly from the <input> or from the date picker. Both of them give the same result : UTC +2 instead of UTC +1

Comment: Still struggeling with this... Help ?